# RTLD_NODELETE synonym for AIX

Tags: aix, dynamic-linking, dlopen

I need my `.so` module to stay loaded even after `dlclose()` call. In Linux since glibc 2.2 I could do that using `RTLD_NODELETE` flag while calling `dlopen`. Is there a way to do the same thing in AIX 6 and newer versions?

Comment: How about _not_ calling `dlclose`? Take no offence, but it sounds like an XY problem to me.

Comment: The problem here really is that I need to be sure that the dll that once was loaded to memory won't be unloaded even after the user tells it to do.